# How do I disable detailed monitoring for instances in an auto scaling group in a CloudFormation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm using CloudFormation to spin up some servers in an auto scaling group, and I want them all to use **basic** monitoring. I tried setting `Monitoring` to `false` in the `AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup` properties as well as the `AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration`, but the stack cannot start up; I see `CREATE_FAILED` with the error message: `Encountered unsupported property Monitoring`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just another day in the lovingly roguish world of almost-but-not-quite-consistant CFN template syntax.

The property you want is `InstanceMonitoring`, not `Monitoring`. It should apply to your LaunchConfiguration resource. More details are [in the docs.](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig.html#cfn-as-launchconfig-instancemonitoring)

```
InstanceMonitoring

Indicates whether or not instance monitoring should be enabled for this
    autoscaling group. This is enabled by default. To turn it off, set
    InstanceMonitoring to "false".

Required: No. Default value is "true".
Type: Boolean
```

Of course, if you're provisioning an AWS::EC2::Instance resource, it's just straight up `Monitoring`. For what it's worth, I find this slightly less annoying than changing `SecurityGroups` to `SecurityGroupIds` when moving Instance declarations in and out of VPCs, but that's just me.