# AWS Cloud formation cfn-init error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create cluster structure using Cloud Formation script. I'm using Bitnami drupal AMI.
Bu the script produces below eror:

```
WaitCondition received failed message: 'Failed to run cfn-init' for uniqueId: i-4d121a16
```

Then I connected to instance and checked cfn-init.log:

```
bitnami@ip-10-58-51-235:/var/log$ cat cfn-init.log                              
2013-01-01 19:18:23,128 [INFO] Starting new HTTP connection (1): 169.254.169.254
2013-01-01 22:52:17,607 [INFO] Starting new HTTP connection (1): 169.254.169.254
2013-01-01 22:52:17,621 [INFO] Starting new HTTPS connection (1): cloudformation-waitcondition-    eu-west-1.s3.amazonaws.com
```

My AWS Console events like below:

Logical ID       PhysicalID                                  Status              Reason

mycluster       arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:318730...  CREATE_FAILED       The following resource(s) failed to create: [WaitCondition]

WaitCondition   vgdrobe-WaitCondition-UWEKNUJ8TMT6          CREATE_FAILED       WaitCondition received failed message: 'Failed to run cfn-init' for uniqueId: i-59272f1c

WaitCondition   vgdrb-WaitCondition-MML6Y6E47WTB            CREATE_IN_PROGRESS

WebServerGroup  vgdrb-WebServerGroup-1OBJYOSQX8093          CREATE_COMPLETE

I couln't find the problem. Could you help me please?

Kind regards...

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the cfn-init scripts are not part of the image?

According to the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-helper-scripts-reference.html), they're installed as part of the Amazon Linux image, but may not be included by default in other images.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on what Chris suggested, I had to add the following to get cfn-init working on my CloudFormation script:

```
"apt-get -y install python-setuptools\n", 
"easy_install https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-1.0.tar.gz\n",
```

I found some really useful info about this here: http://smart421.wordpress.com/2012/12/14/aws-cloudformation-and-chef-on-centos/

I also found errors in my UserData caused cfn-init to fail. I got around this by using VS2012 to validate the script before uploading it (as suggested here: [How can I quickly and effectively debug CloudFormation templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854772/how-can-i-quickly-and-effectively-debug-cloudformation-templates)).

Hope that helps.