# AWS > CloudFormation templates - can you test them before uploading?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

When I upload a CloudFormation template to AWS's Management Console it takes a few minutes for AWS to process the template.

Doing this for say 20 iterations means a significant chunk of time is just waiting for an error message.

Is there anyway to test it prior to uploading it to AWS's Management Console (preferably a bit more than just "is it valid JSON")?

E.g. a tool that ran through:

1. is it valid JSON?
2. is the input to each Resource / Parameter correct?
3. etc...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I quickly and effectively debug CloudFormation templates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854772/how-can-i-quickly-and-effectively-debug-cloudformation-templates)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the aws cli [validate-template](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/validate-template.html) command

### validate-template

```sh
aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://path/to/template
```

In my workflow I have this integrated into a pre-commit git hook to perform some automatic validation

### cfn-lint

There is now an awslabs project called cfn-lint that integrates with a variety of editors, it does a  more extensive linting of templates. It's available from the awslabs on Github

https://github.com/awslabs/cfn-python-lint

This can also be added as a precommit for your cloudformation workflow