# How to debug cloudformation template? Syntax errors in policy. YAML file

Tags: amazon-web-services, configuration, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

Error that I get when deployed a stack:

```
Syntax errors in policy. (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument; Request ID:
```

That's my role policy that cause an error:

```
  roleEc2:
Type: AWS::IAM::Role
Properties:
  AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
    Version: "2012-10-17"
    Statement:
      -
        Effect: Allow
        Principal:
          Service:
            - 'ec2.amazonaws.com'
        Action:
            - 'sts:AssumeRole'
  Path: '/'
  Policies:
    -
      PolicyName: 'bucket-access'
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Id: 'BucketPolicy'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
          - s3:ListBucket
          - s3:GetObject
          - s3:GetBucketLocation
          Resource:
          - arn:aws:s3:::code-dir
          - arn:aws:s3:::code-dir/*
          Principal: !Ref BucketPrincipal
```

And I don't know how to debug it, I don't know how to understand where is an error, what line number.

Comment: root level of the document is a mapping. The first key of that is indented two spaces, the second key zero spaces. That is invalid, they all have to be indented the same amount. If you remove the space before `roleEc2`, and  assuming a constructor for `!Ref` is available, this is valid  YAML.

Comment: Please refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854772/how-can-i-quickly-and-effectively-debug-cloudformation-templates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I know this is a year later but still...) A good tool I like to use is cfn-lint: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint run this against your template and it will show you what you are doing wrong, on what line:

Issues in the code: didn't have first four lines, cannot have principal in IAM Policy (Last line).

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: AoD CloudFormation Template Detective Controls
Resources:
  roleEc2:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          -
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - 'ec2.amazonaws.com'
            Action:
                - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: '/'
      Policies:
        -
          PolicyName: 'bucket-access'
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Id: 'BucketPolicy'
            Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
              - s3:ListBucket
              - s3:GetObject
              - s3:GetBucketLocation
              Resource:
              - arn:aws:s3:::code-dir
              - arn:aws:s3:::code-dir/*
```